# ASP 4.0 IIS HTTP 404

Tags: .net, asp.net, http, iis, .net-4.0

I just installed .NET 4.0 on my Win 2003 Server running IIS. 
I didn't have any problems using ASP.NET 2.0 built websites, but now if I set the ASP.NET version to 4.0 and I deploy a website built using vs2010, I get HTTP 400 http://localhost/mysite/Default.aspx homepage. I have an.xml file in the same folder and browsing to that shows its content as it should, no HTTP 400 error. 
I checked .aspx extensions in IIS configuration/Mappings and the application extension for aspx is set to c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll with verbs set to 'All'. The same issue (http 400) appears for wcf service .svc extension. I can browse though to an .xml document in the same virtual directory. What might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try setting the HTTP runtime's `requestPathInvalidChars` attribute (if there are any bad characters in your URL according to ASP.NET 4):
`<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidChars=""  />`

It could have considered the `:` as bad (are you sure the address was not `localhost:port`?).

**Edit**: [httpRuntime Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) (the new attribute is not listed, yet, but it shows where you should put it in the **web.config**).

Comment: Forgot to mention it, it was indeed localhost:port (81). I created a new Website and in this new website I created my virtual directory I mentioned before.

Comment: I thought so. You could use `<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidChars="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,\,?" />` then. An empty invalid char list would leave you vulnerable. Did it work? Also edited the answer with a link to the `httpRuntime` element.